# What are the highest living rating uncolonized territories in Victoria II?

Tags: victoria-2

I have found the following:

35 Mayotte
35 Comoros
30 South Georgia

What are the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full listing of provinces is listed on the [Vick2Wiki](http://www.paradoxian.org/vicky2wiki/Main_Page), which includes the provinces owner at the start of the game and the province's life rating. The list can be sorted by life rating and then owner to show the highest living rating uncolonised territories. The highest living rating for an uncolonised territory is 35, as you've discovered. The province list is [here](http://www.paradoxian.org/vicky2wiki/Provinces).

**Uncolonised territories with living rating 35:**

> Alamosa, Ashkhabad, Baker City, Banff, Boise, Calgary, Comoros,
>   Denver, Dikoa, Grand Junction, Kelowna, Kizil Arvat, Klamath Falls,
>   Kuka, Massekisse, Mayotte, Mossurize, Nampula, Nguru, Oklahoma City,
>   Okmulgee, Ootomari, Pocatello, Pogobi, Portland, Prince George,
>   Pueblo, Seattle, Spokane, Tahlequah, Vernon, Walla Walla

**Uncolonised territories with living rating 30:**

> Alor, Asquith, Athabaska Landing, Beatton River, Christchurch,
>   Dauphin, Denwood, Dunedin, Edmonton, Fasher, Fort Chipewyan, Fort
>   Saint John, Goba, Hokitika, Indian Lakes, Jasper, Napier, Negele,
>   Norway House, Prince Albert, Saskatoon, South Georgia, Stanley, Werder